# How can I delete multiple tasks from an App Engine Pull queue with a single request using the REST API?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, task-queue

[The documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-pull.html#Using_the_Task_Queue_REST_API_with_the_Python_Google_API_Library) under 'Deleting Tasks' says

> You can delete an individual task or a list of tasks using the REST method Tasks.delete.

but doesn't indicate how to do this. The [discovery-doc](https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/taskqueue/v1beta1/rest) for the method shows only a string param, `task`.

Is there something that I'm missing, or is the only solution to send multiple delete requests?

Comment: I agree to you, it does not seem to be possible using the REST API.